# ssrs user typing in multiple values in a parameter or leaving it blank

Tags: sql, reporting-services, split, ssrs-2012

I am creating a report in SSRS and have a parameter for the end users to search for an account number. Within the report the parameter is set to null by default to show all accounts. When the parameter is not null the user should be able to type in a single account or multiple accounts separated by commas. My problem is when I try to type in multiple accounts I get this error:

"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','."

Here is my sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_db WHERE (AccountNumber IN (@Account)) OR (@Account IS NULL)
```

The code on the parameter for @Account is

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!Account.Value),Parameters!Account.Value,Split(Parameters!Account.Value,","))
```

Comment: How is @Account declared?

Comment: SELECT * FROM test_db WHERE (AccountNumber IN (@Account)) OR (AccountNumber  IS NULL)   You might mean this. AccountNumber  instead of @Account in OR

Comment: @Account is a data type Text in SSRS and a varchar(30) in the database.

I tried adjusting the sql query to your suggestion but then it doesn't display all the accounts when the parameter is left null

Comment: You need to use Dynamic SQL. Something like ..  exec ('select * from test_db where (AccountNumber in (' + @Account + ')) OR AccountNumber IS NULL' )

Comment: Is it comma deliminated? if so you need to split it to do the In statement.

Comment: Yes. As per SnowLockk, you need to comma delimite for @AccountNumber variable for int or if string or date need single quotes for each account number

Comment: You don't need to do anything with it. If you make the @Account parameter multi-value, you can simply type each entry followed by [Enter], no commas, just your required value, one on each row of the parameter drop down. Then your original query will work, SSRS will automatically convert the multi-value list into a comma separated list and inject it into your SQL. It this doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll put a complete answer with some images. You may need to change the last bit part to OR (ISNULL(@Account, '' ) = ' ') this take care of blanks too

Comment: Yes the user would type them in with commas. So 00440127,00300002 and I did use a split in the parameter.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Alan when I change the parameter to Allow Multiple values I am returned with no values when I first run the report. When it is first ran it should run all accounts. I tried to populate the parameter with another dataset but then it doesn't allow me to type in the drop down if I want to just look for 1 specific account.

Comment: You need to allow nulls and blanks on the parameter and set the default value to null.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I was able to add the blank value to the parameter, but nulls aren't allowed with the multiple value option selected.

After doing this I am now returned with values when it is blank, and when I type in a single account. But when I type in 2 accounts I get an error:
    The isnull function requires 2 argument(s).

Comment: I'll put it ans a answer so the code is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything with it. If you make the @Account parameter multi-value, you can simply type each entry followed by [Enter], no commas, just your required value, one on each row of the parameter drop down.

[image]

Then your original query will work, SSRS will automatically convert the multi-value list into a comma separated list and inject it into your SQL. If this doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll put a complete answer with some images. You may need to change you query to

```
SELECT * 
    FROM test_db 
    WHERE AccountNumber IN (@Account) 
        OR ISNULL(@Account, '' ) = ''
```

This will take care of blanks too. So blanks/Null should return everything

Comment: I am typing in the accounts and hitting enter, but I still get the same error: "The isnull function requires 2 argument(s)". I can search for 1 account, and if I leave it blank I am returned with all accounts. I just can't get multiple accounts to work. I did change my query as well - SSRS does change it to the below once I edit it.

        SELECT * FROM test_db WHERE (UtilityAccountNumber IN @Account)) OR (ISNULL(@Account, '') = '')

Comment: Can you post your dataset query. As you can see from the code snippet I posted, the ISNULL function is getting two arguments, it's getting @Account and then an empty string (two single quotes '') so it should work.